# Flask-SQLAlchemy create_all()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When i run the dbManager.create_all() command, it runs with out errors but fails to create the tables. When i delete the database and run the create_all() command, i get the no such database as ##### error which i should get but when the database does exist, nothing happens.
Please can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

```
from blogconfig import dbManager


class Art(dbManager.Model):
    id = dbManager.Column(dbManager.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = dbManager.Column(dbManager.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    content = dbManager.Column(dbManager.Text(5000))




    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Art %r>' %(self.title)
```

EDIT
This is the shell command

```
from blogconfig import dbManager
>>> dbManager.create_all()



 import models

>>> a = models.Art(title='des', content='asdfvhbdjbjdn')
>>> dbManager.session.add(a)
>>> dbManager.session.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 721, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 354, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 334, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1818, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1936, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 58, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1900, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 372, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 525, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 64, in save_obj
    table, insert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 569, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 761, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 195, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'blog.art' doesn't exist") 'INSERT INTO art (title, content) VALUES (%s, %s)' ('des', 'asdfvhbdjbjdn')
```

Comment: if you would publish also the shell commands you execute it would be much easier to tell you what you are missing.

Comment: It's impossible for us to know the issue because you have discussed an issue that relates to your entire codebase. You'll need to investigate the issue more to be able to pinpoint where the problem is occurring yourself. I would recommend enabling SQLAlchemy logging and making sure that the database tables are being created correctly during the `create_all()` call. I imagine that you're importing things incorrectly, causing the metadata to not be filled, so `create_all()` does not recognize that it needs to create tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dbManager will not know about the models you define in other modules unless they are imported before running `create_all`.

In a real application this shouldn't matter because running the flask app should set up the db and import views/blueprints to register them.  Since the views use the models, the models are indirectly imported and are available to the dbManager.

Either import your models in the `blogconfig` module after creating the dbManager instance, or change the order of you shell commands to be

```
>>> from blogconfig import dbManager
>>> import models
>>> dbManager.create_all()
```

SQLAlchemy will only create tables, the database must already exist, which is why you're seeing the other error when you delete the database.