# How does Flask-SQLAlchemy create_all discover the models to create?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLAlchemy's `db.create_all()` method creates each table corresponding to my defined models.  I never instantiate or register instances of the models. They're just class definitions that inherit from `db.Model`.  How does it know which models I have defined?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy does nothing special, it's all a standard part of SQLAlchemy.

Calling [`db.create_all`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/1d8e9873bed9e8b75a9e7b0903870fe832b92628/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L967) eventually calls [`db.Model.metadata.create_all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all).  Tables are [associated with a `MetaData` instance as they are defined](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.metadata).  The exact mechanism is very circuitous within SQLAlchemy, as there is a lot of behind the scenes bookkeeping going on, so I've greatly simplified the explanation.

`db.Model` is a [declarative base class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base), which has some special metaclass behavior.  When it is defined, it creates a `MetaData` instance internally to store the tables it generates for the models.  When you subclass `db.Model`, its metaclass behavior records the class in `db.Model._decl_class_registry` as well as the table in `db.Model.metadata`.

---

Classes are only defined when the modules containing them are imported.  If you have a module `my_models` written somewhere, but it is never imported, its code never executes so the models are never registered.

This may be where some confusion about how SQLAlchemy detects the models comes from.  No modules are "scanned" for subclasses, `db.Model.__subclasses__` is not used, but importing the modules somewhere *is* required for the code to execute.

1. Module containing models is imported and executed.
2. Model class definition is executed, subclasses `db.Model`
3. Model's table is registered with `db.Model.metadata`

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `create_all()` in the same module as all the models are in. If they are in separate modules, you need to import them all before calling `create_all()`. SQLAlchemy looks at what models have been subclassed from `db.Model`, and it will only see models that have been imported. It will create the corresponding table for each model. Also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460527/flask-sqlalchemy-create-all).

Comment: I found the `globals()` builtin method (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#globals) which lists all the symbols in the current module. Iterating through the result and filtering classes which inherit db.Model seems to be a pretty straight-forward solution.

Comment: Actually it does not need to go through all classes in the module. If all the models have been imported, db.Model.__subclasses__() will give you all the classes that inherit from db.Model