# Manage models with cloudsql (mysql instance google cloud platform)

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have an app engine project and I want to use MySQL instance (google cloud platform) to store my datas.

I can connect to my instance by using this [tuto](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/cloudsql/main.py).

So now I want to know how to create a model like :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Visit(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    user_ip = db.Column(db.String(46))

    def __init__(self, timestamp, user_ip):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.user_ip = user_ip
```

And add it in my instance, and if I add a field in my model how to update it with my instance.

Comment: The `db` library (and its recommended replacement `ndb`) apply to the cloud datastore (a nosql solution), not to cloudsql/mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the model you’re updating is a SQLAlchemy model, updating the code and running the SQLAlchemy.create_all() method should take care of it You can take a look at an example [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#quickstart).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082692/how-does-flask-sqlalchemy-create-all-discover-the-models-to-create) is also a great answer to a similar question. It explains how and when tables are updated by SQLAlchemy.